# Remove spaces in batch variable

Tags: batch-file

So I have these two variables, a and c, they both have a space after them so when I'm trying to join them it prints "a c " and not "ac". How should I go on about removing the spaces?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
set "a=%a: =%"
```

is one way. set the variable=%variablename:stringtoreplace=replacementstring%

The quotes ensure that any trailing spaces in the `set` line are not included into the value assigned.

The replacement string may be empty.

This is a general solution, replacing *all* strings matching *stringtoreplace* with the defined replacement.